# Trimethylsilyl iodide - Alkyne Reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, protecting-groups

I have synthesized the molecule below possessing a doubly, boc protected heterocyclic amine and a terminal alkyne.

Upon attempting a TFA/$\ce{CH2Cl2}$ Boc deprotection I believe my alkyne is being hydrolysed.

1.) I wish to use TMSI to perform the boc deprotection but cannot find information on how it acts in the presence of alkynes. Would TMSI iodinate, silylate or otherwise interact with the alkyne?

2.) Is there any way to make use of TFA/$\ce{CH2Cl2}$ and prevent the alkyne hydrolysis?

[image]

Comment: Can you use HCl/Dioxane?

Comment: @Waylander why do you think this would help? Also, I imagine the hydrolysis is because of the presence of water? Is this theory correct?

Comment: HCl/Dioxane is a method we use extensively for removing BOC groups. Vac down hard to remove xs HCl before adding water should prevent any hydrolysis, indeed you may not need aq workup. How are you working up the TFA deprotection?

Comment: Have you tried just heating it? One of my colleagues had really good luck with simple thermolysis. I would think that the first Boc will fall off easily at least.

Comment: The first BOC should come off with nucleophiles eg MeO-. What concentration of TFA are you using?

Comment: @Waylander Workup was a simple NaHCO3 wash whilst extracting with EtOAc. I've used HCl/Dioxane before, but due to time constraints and expense this may not be currently possible. What's your take on the TMSI? Looking at page 5 of the following paper's supporting info., it seems doable. [link](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/cb400261h)

Comment: TMSiI looks a good option. Seems unlikely to attack the alkyne. With regard to the TFA reaction it might be worth vaccing down hard to remove all the TFA before exposure to aq.

Comment: Seems unlikely that you're attacking the alkyne directly. You might be getting break down somewhere else...

Comment: @Zhe without divulging the sturcture of the heteroaromatic, I can tell you that I've made a range of molecules possessing the same heteroaromatic core and all of them are TFA stable. The only difference here is the alkyne which none of the other molecules had.

Comment: I could you could form the ketone from the alkyne though that still seems kind of unlikely. Have consulted Greene/Wuts? That's kind of the goto reference for protecting groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TMSI was used successfully without damaging the alkyne as per this protocol.

http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/cb400261h